# Comparing items from foreach to another foreach item in Asp MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, foreach

I have a class like so:

```
public class AddingNewRole
{
    public List<LookUpRole> LookUpRoles { get; set; }
    public List<AddNewRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}

public class AddNewRole
{
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
}

public class LookUpRole{
    public int LookUpRoleId { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public string RoleDescription { get; set; }
}
```

I use it in my controller to pass it to my view like so:

```
public ActionResult GetAccountRoles(int accountId)
{
    var am = new AdministrationManager();
    var result = am.GetAllRoles(accountId);
    return PartialView(result);
}
```

What I want to have in my view is to list all the LookUpRoles(there are actually 4 of them - "Administrator, Guest, Member, and Security") and a checkbox that when the `LookUpRoleId` is in the `UserRole`, meaning `LookUpRoleId == RoleId`, it should be checked and if not, then the checkbox should be unchecked. With my code below, I can get the list of LookUpRoles but each of its row has 2 checkboxes when it should only contain 1.
Below is what I have:

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication3.Models.ViewModel.AddingNewRole>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
{
    foreach (var v in item.LookUpRoles)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => v.LookUpRoleId)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => v.RoleName)
            </td>
            @for(var i=0; i<item.UserRoles.Count();i++)
            {
                if (v.LookUpRoleId == item.UserRoles[i].RoleId)
                {
                    <td>
                        <input id=@v.LookUpRoleId  class="use-this switch-toggle switch-flat-mini switch-toggle-flat" type="checkbox">
                        <label for=@v.LookUpRoleId></label>
                    </td>
                break;
                }
                <td>
                    <input id=@v.LookUpRoleId checked="checked" class="use-this switch-toggle switch-flat-mini switch-toggle-flat" type="checkbox">
                    <label for=@v.LookUpRoleId></label>
                </td>
                break;
            }

        </tr>
    }
}
```

Where am I getting the wrong logic or implementation? Thank you.

Comment: shouldn't your model be `AddingNewRole` rather

Comment: Are you seeing the 2 checkbox's when viewing the source? Is one hidden?

Comment: Please look at my edit. Now I can just see one checkbox.

Comment: Its terrible practice to put that logic in a view. You view model should have properties `int RoleId`, `string RoleName` and `bool IsSelected` and you bind the checkbox using `@Html.CheckboxFor()` inside a `for` loop - your logic goes in the controller, not the view (although you do not even have a form so its not clear why you have a checkbox)

Comment: @Stephen Thank you. I see now the terrible practice. I'll try to change my code the way you said it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do what you want:

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication3.Models.ViewModel.AddingNewRole>
<tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    foreach (var v in item.LookUpRoles)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => v.LookUpRoleId)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => v.RoleName)
            </td>           
            <td>
                <input id=@v.LookUpRoleId
                    @(item.UserRoles.Any(r => r.RoleId == v.LookUpRoleId) ? "checked=\"checked\"" : String.Empty)
                    class="use-this switch-toggle switch-flat-mini switch-toggle-flat" type="checkbox">
                <label for=@v.LookUpRoleId></label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
}
</tbody>
```

This just adds the `checked="checked"` if any role of the user is the current lookup-role.

Comment: Elegant. Thank you very much!

Comment: ...but please take a look at the comment of @StephenMuecke - he is absolutely right with what he says ;-)...

Comment: I'm trying to figure out the way to do it properly. Thanks again.